# How do I show equivalence between $\frac{(x^2 + 1)^{5/2}}{5} - \frac{(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}}{3}$ and $\frac{(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}(3x^2 - 2)}{15}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wanted to find $\int x^3 \sqrt{x^2 + 1} dx$ and came to this answer:

$$\frac{(x^2 + 1)^{5/2}}{5} - \frac{(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}}{3}$$

Using software to verify, I find Maple does not show equivalence between this and the actual answer, yet an online integral calculator does show equivalence between this and the actual answer with a footnote that further simplification does yield the expected answer.

For reference, the actual answer is:

$$\frac{(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}(3x^2 - 2)}{15}$$

How do I show algebraically that these two are equivalent? I could plug in $x$ for an arbitrary amount of numbers and compare but I want to be more declarative and show equality algebraically.

I've tried to combine this into one fraction:

$$\begin{align}
 & \frac{(x^2 + 1)^{5/2}}{5} - \frac{(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}}{3} \\
=& \frac{3\times(x^2 + 1)^{5/2}}{3\times5} - \frac{5\times(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}}{5\times3} \\
=& \frac{3(x^2 + 1)^{5/2}}{15} - \frac{5(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}}{15} \\
=& \frac{3(x^2+1)^{5/2} - 5(x^2+1)^{3/2}}{15}
\end{align}$$

But I am not sure where or how else to go from here.

Comment: Take $(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor out $(x^2+1)^{3/2}$:

$$\frac{(x^2 + 1)^{5/2}}{5} - \frac{(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}}{3}$$

$$=(x^2+1)^{3/2}\left(\dfrac{x^2+1}5-\dfrac13\right)$$

$$=(x^2+1)^{3/2}\;\dfrac{[3(x^2+1)-5]}{15}$$

$$=(x^2+1)^{3/2}\;\dfrac{(3x^2-2)}{15}$$

Or from where you left off:

$$\frac{3(x^2+1)^{5/2} - 5(x^2+1)^{3/2}}{15}$$

$$=(x^2+1)^{3/2}\;\dfrac{[3(x^2+1)-5]}{15}$$

$$=(x^2+1)^{3/2}\;\dfrac{(3x^2-2)}{15}$$

Comment: Appreciate it. Interestingly, internally Maple was simplifying my answer to $\frac{1}{15} \times (x(3x^2 - 2)^2 + 1)^{3/2}$.